# Django Form validation error

Tags: python, django

Trying my first app in Django, and have some problem on form validation (following documentation)
This is part of file upload code. The form creates fine. But, the validation fails.
Even though, I provide `Title`, it gives `This field is required.`

### views.py

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            #TODO handle(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('setup.html', {'form': form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

### forms.py

```
from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    file = forms.FileField()
```

### setup.html

```
<form action="/setup/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `required` paremeter to your form field. [If you don't provide it Django will assume it is required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#required).

`title = forms.CharField(required=False)`